# Fabric Answers Event: how to see all custom attributes?

Tags: crashlytics, google-fabric

In my app when user reports a spelling error in the table row I send an event with a name `mistake` with custom attribute `id` that contains `id` of the row.

In my case it's possible to have more than 400 different values but in Fabric I see only top 100.

[image]

Is there a way to see all of them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Fabric, we show the top 10 and there isn't a way to see the full 400. If you link your app to Firebase you can access up to 25 attributes. Check out https://docs.fabric.io/apple/answers/ios-export-firebase.html for more details.

Comment: The link is dead. So what's happen?